# Slider code, doesn't work as scrubber, won't move when down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, slider

What breaks is the scrubbing slider, it recognises a click, but it does not move. I have interactable enable.

I'm having to reimport all assets to get it to work again but even now this isn't a sure bet it'll fix it.

This code was working perfectly fine about a week ago, I've made little changes to it since.

A lot of it is commented so I can learn that different parts of the code. Feel free to delete it if it bothers you.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class NewAnimController : MonoBehaviour {


public Slider scrubSlider;    //This is the slider that controls the current position of the animation. Values have to be 0 to 1 for normalized time of the animation, called later in the script
public Slider speedSlider;       //This is the slider that controls the playback speed of the animation
public Animator animator;        //Animator that is attached to the model that we are looking to control the animation of
public float playbackSpeedAdjustment = 0.5f;  //This is a variable that can be easily adjusted to change the total playback speed of the animation. If it's too fast make smaller and vice versa
public Text currentDateText;
public int monthsInProject;

private float rememberTheSpeedBecauseWeMightNeedIt;  //Float needed to keep the speed of the animation between pausing and playing

public void Update()
{
    float animationTime = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime;   //float a new value animationTime that is equal to the animators animation state then converted to normalized time
    //Debug.Log("animationTime (normalized) is " + animationTime);   //logging the normalized time to be able to store it for the scrubbing slider. Doesn't need to be logged for this to work, good to log it to make sure that it's working
    scrubSlider.value = animationTime;  //making the slider value equal to the now logged normalized time of the animation state

}


public void ScrubSliderChanged(float ScrubSliderchangedValue)  // this value has to be floated so that the scrubbing slider can be attached to in the inspector to be able to change the current frame of the animation
{
    animator.Play("Take 001", -1, scrubSlider.normalizedValue);

}


public void SpeedSliderChanged(float SpeedSliderchangedValue)  //value is floated to be able to change the speed of the animation playback
{
    animator.speed = speedSlider.normalizedValue * playbackSpeedAdjustment;  // here the speed is multiplied by the adjustment value set in the editor just in case the playback speed needs to be changed outside of normalized values
}


public void UserClickedPauseButton()
{
    if (animator.speed > 0f)
    {
        // we need to pause animator.speed
        rememberTheSpeedBecauseWeMightNeedIt = animator.speed;
        animator.speed = 0f;
    }
    else
    {
        // we need to "unpause"
        animator.speed = rememberTheSpeedBecauseWeMightNeedIt;
    }
}

public void UserClickedBackButton()
{
    scrubSlider.value = scrubSlider.value - (1f / monthsInProject);
}

public void UserClickedForwardButton()
{
    scrubSlider.value = scrubSlider.value + (1f / monthsInProject);
}

public void UserClickedStartButton()
{
    scrubSlider.value = 0;
}

public void UserClickedEndButton()
{
    scrubSlider.value = 1;
}
}
```

Many thanks for all your help.

Comment: `NewAnimController` is not a good name dude.  Should be like `Scrubber`, perhaps.

Comment: This will be a very interesting question for anyone working with `Slider`, so I did edit out the not-relevant-to-the-problem slab of code.  Good one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is this. In `Update` you are doing something like this:

```
scrubSlider.value = animationTime
```

that means that every frame, "NO MATTER WHAT", YOU ARE SETTING THE SLIDER POSITION, to, where the animation is. If the user is trying to move the slider - **you are moving it right back, that same frame!**

It's not so easy to solve this problem. Unity did not include a trivial built-in function for this. You need a separate script which sits on the slider which determines whether or not the handle is being held down. You have to use the `OnPointerDown` and `OnPointerUp` handlers.

## How to use pointer handlers in modern Unity:

Step one, make this small script called `Teste.cs`

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class Teste:MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
    {
    public Slider theSlider;
    public bool sliderIsBeingHeldDown;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
        {
        sliderIsBeingHeldDown = true;
        Debug.Log("holding down!");
        }
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData data)
        {
        sliderIsBeingHeldDown = false;
        Debug.Log("holding up!");
        }
    }
```

## Don't forget the declaration...

```
Teste:MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
```

rather than the usual `MonoBehavior`.

Drag that script **on to** your `UI.Slider`.

## Note that in general these only work when they are "on" the thing in question.

Run, and try clicking up and down on the slider button - check the console.  It works right? Now you have to use that variable inside `NewAnimController`

(1) Add a public variable to `NewAnimController`,

```
public Teste teste;
```

(2) Be sure to drag to connect that variable in Inspector

(3) Now you can refer to `teste.sliderIsBeingHeldDown` to see if that slider is being held down. So instead of doing this every frame...

```
scrubSlider.value = animationTime;
```

you will have to do this every frame...

```
if (teste.sliderIsBeingHeldDown)
  Debug.Log("don't try to work against the user!");
else
  scrubSlider.value = animationTime;
```

I hope that works!  I *think* that's the simplest way to know when the slider is being held-down.

You really chose a difficult project for your first project! Hell!

It's worth noting that you could also put the slider-adjusting code (I mean to say your actual code for the scrubber) "inside" the script that is actually on the slider -- but I wouldn't worry about that for now. Your solution as stands is good.

*Note* depending on how you implement it, you may need to make it pause more elegantly when you hold down the slider handle, but before moving the slider handle. To achieve this, one approach is arrange to call `UserClickedPauseButton()` or a similar concept, when, the Down/Up routines shown here in "Teste", are called. Conversely you could just not bother with `ScrubSliderChanged`, and instead do the whole job inside code that runs whenever the handle is "down".

(In general, you'd almost certainly use `UnityEvent` here to make a solid reusable solution for a slider such as this for use with something like a scrubber.)

Comment: This isn't working as it doesn't pick up on the slider being clicked when the code is implemented within the `NewAnimController` script. `Teste` works fine and is logging the slider being clicked, doesn't log anything when put into `NewAnimController`

Comment: I've just reverted the code back to the very first one that worked `{

    public Slider sliderScrubber;
    public Animator animator;

    public void Update()
    {
        float animationTime = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime;
        Debug.Log("animationTime (normalized) is " + animationTime);
        sliderScrubber.value = animationTime;
    }

    public void OnValueChanged(float changedValue)
    {
        animator.Play("Take 001", -1, sliderScrubber.normalizedValue);
    }
}` This works perfectly as a scrubber, I don't understand how I've gone wrong elsewhere.

Comment: I did that with the `NewAnimController` script, it's not doing anything. Even when I put it in the script that does work it's not giving me anything back in the console outside of the `teste` script. I think it's got something to do with it doesn't know what slider to be checking you've clicked seeing as there are two sliders within the `NewAnimController` script.

Comment: haha, I don't think it's that difficult is it? That works perfectly, thanks. Now what do I do about the current month read out? I'll check to see if my `else if` code works and doesn't make it break again. I know you don't like `else if` statements though. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: now that we have a script that knows if the handle is being held down is there chance to have the animation pause when the handle is being held down?

Comment: hmm, that should work at the moment - it doesn't?  what happens if you hold down the handle, and then move it slghtly one way or the other?

Comment: OK i THINK this is your best approach to make it pause more elegantly when you hold down: IN THE SCRIPT TESTE, have a public variable for NewAnimController. (so, public NewAnimController nac). Then in BOTH OnPointerDown and OnPointerUp, just after the "Debug" lines , you actually call nac.UserClickedPauseButton().  It makes sense?